# Diferença da tag incial do php

Tags: php

Recentemente tenho explorado muitos códigos relacionados com php, scripts, consultas etc, porém me deparei com uma coisa!

Na tag incial do php o usuário colocou o padrão:

```
<?php echo('test md5:' . md5_file('index.php'); ?>
```

porém depois de aberta / fechada a tag php o camarada iniciou outra tag, eu infelizmente não conheço!

```
<? include('score.php'); ?>
```

> E qual a diferença de `<?php ?>` e  `<? ?>` ?

Comment: É apenas uma maneira de abreviar... tem servidores que aceitam essa abreviação onde a opção "short open tags" está ativada. Mas eu não aconselho abreviar dessa forma. Se algum servidor não aceitar problemas poderão ocorrer.

Comment: Responde para poder marcar como respondida!

Comment: O ideal é não usar. Ela tem o mesmo efeito de `<?php`, mas pode conflitar com instruções e declaração XML. Pra conhecer estas e a tag curta de echo, veja a postagem linkada acima. Como ja temos varias respostas falando disto, o fechamento serve pra concentrar todas as soluções num lugar só, e a sua pergunta é útil como mecanismo de indexação para que mais pessoas encontrem estas informações.

Comment: Interessante! Sou iniciante e me deparei com essa diferença e fiquei meio perdido!